# Add valuable dynamic content to a mobile oriented (local) website, any suggestions?

Tags: content, mobile

HI to all,

I'm developing a mobile website containing some valuable dynamic content for people living in my city. I did find some useful informations that aren't available in a quick, light mobile format and I added to my site: teathers' programming, pharmacy shops open at night, twitter account embedding... have you got any other suggestion? I was thinking about facebook oauth to add some "social" feel, but I woluld like to avoid cloning fb information/features, just add some other cool addictive thing. I 'm using php for dynamic contents.

Answer (score 1):

How about weather in the city.

Or if it has an ocean, ocean conditions, e.g. water is warm today, go swim!

Answer (score 1):

Music gigs/theatre/comedy listings that day

Sports results/news?

Local blogs?

My city has a nice [daily photo blog](http://newcastleupontynedailyphoto.com/) something similar integrated into a website could be cool.

Answer (score 1):

A nice Google Maps feature that allows people to look up "places".

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

Answer (score 1):

You should get:

- the weather and all climate related things you can find (rain, wind, etc.).
- the events: sports, locals, any leasure-related
- local hot spot: main bars and good place for spending time
- administration-related things: where to ask for any paper you need, etc.

Then, add some geo-localization, and you'll be able to:

- propose a "What to do now" based on weather+events with time (e.g. propose beach on a sunny day, show music concert on a rainy day)
- propose a "What to do here" based on places+events with geolocalization (e.g. propose a bar in which there is a free concert, or a nice french restaurant)
- propose a "How to do this" that explain how to do certain task (e.g. renew your driving license, ask for new ID papers)

After that, you can monetize your site with local-targeted advertising.